# How can I put SP results into temp table in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I have tried this:

```
select * into #temp124
exec usp_GetTagDetails @UserId=1,@IsActiveOnly=1,@IsParentPathRequired=1
```

But this isn't working. Can someone help me to put SP results into temporary table?

Comment: Please show the error message or describe the unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

At first enable few options:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Then you can use [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp124
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local)\InstanceName;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC usp_GetTagDetails @UserId=1,@IsActiveOnly=1,@IsParentPathRequired=1')
```

Another way to create table to store data from SP manually, but you should know exactly what data this SP returns.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp124 (
    Col1 int,
    Col2 nvarchar=(max),
    ...etc
)

INSERT INTO #temp124
EXEC usp_GetTagDetails @UserId=1,@IsActiveOnly=1,@IsParentPathRequired=1
```